# How should C++ objects be serialized?

Tags: c++, serialization, ipc, mpi

We are doing a project on high performance computing, which using MPI as parallel computing framework. There are just a few algorithms already implemented on legacy platform. What we do is rewriten the original serial algorithm to parallel version based on MPI.

I encounter this performance problem: When running parallel algorithm based on MPI, there are a lot of comunication overhead between multiple process. The inter-process comunication is consist of three steps:

1. Process A serialize some C++ objects into binary format.
2. Process A send binary format data to Process B by MPI.
3. Process B deserialize binary format data into C++ objects.

We found these comunication steps, especially serialize/deserialize steps, cost huge amount of time. How could we hand this performance issue?

By the Way, in our C++ code, We use a lot of STL, which is more complex then C-like struct.

P.S. I am doing this(serialization) now by written code traversing all fields of the objects and copy them sequentially into a byte array.

To demonstrate what I doing, there is a code snippet. Note that this is just a single feature construction process:

```
sic::GeometryFeature *ptFeature =
    (GeometryFeature *) outLayer->getFeature(iFeature);
sic::Geometry* geom = ptFeature->getGeometry();
std::string geomClassName = geom->getClassName();

sic::Geometry* ptGeom = geom;
unsigned char *wkbBuffer = NULL;
OGRGeometry * gtGeom = NULL;
if (geomClassName == "Point") {
    ptGeom = new sic::MultiPoint();
    ((sic::MultiPoint *) ptGeom)->insert(geom);
    gtGeom = new OGRMultiPoint();
    int wkbSize = ((sic::MultiPoint *) ptGeom)->WkbSize();
    wkbBuffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(wkbSize);
    ((sic::GeometryCollection *) ptGeom)->exportToWkb(sic::wkbNDR,
        wkbBuffer, wkbMultiPoint);
}
} else if (...) {
    ......
}
gtGeom->importFromWkb(wkbBuffer);
free(wkbBuffer);
assert(gtGeom);
OGRFeature * poFeature = OGRFeature::CreateFeature(
     poLayer->GetLayerDefn());
poFeature->SetGeometry(gtGeom);
```

And more about What I am doing serializing objects:

```
unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char *) malloc(size);
    size_t offset = 0;

    size_t type_size = sizeof(OGRwkbGeometryType);
    OGRwkbGeometryType type = layer->GetGeomType();
    memcpy(bytes + offset, &type, type_size);
    offset += type_size;

    size_t count_size = sizeof(int);
    int count = layer->GetFeatureCount();
    memcpy(bytes + offset, &count, count_size);
    offset += count_size;

    layer->ResetReading();
    for (OGRFeature *feature = layer->GetNextFeature(); feature != NULL;
            feature = layer->GetNextFeature()) {
        OGRGeometry *geometry = feature->GetGeometryRef();
        if (geometry) {
            geometry->exportToWkb(wkbNDR, bytes + offset);
            offset += geometry->WkbSize();
        } else {
            (*(int *) (bytes + type_size))--;
        }
        OGRFeature::DestroyFeature(feature);
    }

    return bytes;
```

Any Comment will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How are you serializing now, and what part of that is most expensive?

Comment: @Useless I am doing this(serialization) now by written code traversing all fields of the objects and copy them sequentially into a byte array.

Comment: What's the point of the byte array, when you could write them directly to the stream?  Anyway, why not have a look at boost serialisation - it should give you some ideas about good practice, and something benchmark against.  You haven't given us enough information to provide you useful advice re. your current implementation.

Comment: @TonyD Good point. I have not used boost serialisation because it is heavy, and I do not want more complexity. I'll check implementation of boost serialisation.

Comment: @lulyon: bits of boost are often heavy in terms of complexity of source code - in particular there's lots of ugly cruft to make things more portable - but that doesn't necessarily mean they don't perform well at runtime.

Comment: If you know the program's bottleneck is the serialization, the profiler that told you about that bottleneck should be able to identify what *part* of the serialization is the bottleneck.

Comment: @TonyD I think I get what you mean, thanks.

Comment: @ArneMertz Yes, we have used profilers to track the performance bottleneck, and have concluded that the whole serialization method should be rewritten the solve the problem. But I've no idea how.

Comment: Well, serialisation doesn't have to be hard.  If you give some specific examples of the data types and containers you're using, we could work through what you basically want the code to achieve.  Typically it's pretty simple: you have X bytes of data in memory so you want to write out those X bytes to the stream, but you need to think a bit about whether the meaning of the streamed data needs to survive transmission between big & little-endian systems intact, ensure alignment on deserialisation, and pick some conventions for specifying variable lengths (e.g. using a 32-bit prefixed length).

Comment: It sounds pretty much like what you're doing...?  If you show us a few examples of your serialisation code we can see if there's anything obviously suspect....

Comment: @TonyD Yes, but the object inheritance structure is hugh and lengthy, so I can't put the whole code, even one object definition here. Your comments are illuminating. I am considering byte order and alignment, but I do not know how to gain performance so far.

Comment: @lulyon could you give us an idea how you do the serialization to binary today and where the bottleneck(s) is in that serialization algorithm? Up to now we do not know much more than "serialization to binary is expensive" - there's not much to say about what algorithm would be better or how your algorithm can be improved if we don't know it.

Comment: @ArneMertz As I've mentioned, I am doing this(serialization) now by written code traversing all fields of the objects and copy them sequentially into a byte array. I know my question is more or less general. But I do want to know if there are some generic mechanism doing serialization well in terms of performance?

Comment: Well, a few things to think about: you could compare the performance of your endianness-handling functions to ntohl et al if you're not already using those.  Are both the serialisation and deserialisation performing similarly?  If the time for memory allocation is significant, then deserialisation should be the slower as you'll generally be requesting heap memory on the fly.  Things like reserving capacity immediately rather than allowing repeated resizes as elements are inserted may help.  You could instrument/time to see if particular containers or data types are disproportionately slow....

Comment: "written code traversing all fields of the objects and copy them sequentially into a byte array" - unfortunately, that's vague.  If you have a container then run-time traversal/iteration is necessary, but if it's a structure it performs better to hardcode the serialisation of each needed field rather than using any kind of generic runtime field access/traversal method you might have added in.  That's the kind of thing we could easily spot if we saw some of your code, but I do appreciate you point about it being hard to extract a useful slice.

Comment: A couple more (likely final sans code for us to look at) thought - if you have factory methods deciding which static types to instantiate during deserialisation, just make sure that the type switching is sensibly direct - e.g. driven by an enum or int rather than lengthy textual typename comparisons.  Additionally, be careful of unnecessary copies, such as appending incoming data to a local `std::string` character by character only to copy it off to a variable's member: rather, thing about using pointers/offsets/lengths to directly move data to it's final deserialised location.  Profile! :-)

Comment: @TonyD Please find the newly attached code in my question.

Comment: @ArneMertz Please find the newly attached code in my question.

Comment: Thanks for posting code... I'm calling it a day here, but will definitely look over it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Brian's answer's offering to help you use a library... he's a very experienced programmer - sounds like it could be worth a go.)

Separately, I looked at your code - there's lots of temporary buffers, new/malloc allocation, use of `sizeof` etc.. so I thought I'd illustrate a "quick, simple but nice" approach to cleaning that up - enough to hopefully get you started...

First create a binary stream type that factors and hides a lot of the low-level work:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h> // for htonl/s, ntoh/s
#include <endian.h> // for htonbe64, if you have it...

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

// support routines - use C++ overloading to polymorphically dispatch htonl/s

// uint64_t hton(uint64_t n) { return htonbe64(n); }
uint32_t hton(uint32_t n) { return htonl(n); }
uint16_t hton(uint16_t n) { return htons(n); }

// there are no "int" versions - this is ugly but effective...
uint32_t hton(int32_t n) { return htonl(n); }
uint16_t hton(int16_t n) { return htons(n); }

// uint64_t ntoh(uint64_t n) { return betoh64(n); }
uint32_t ntoh(uint32_t n) { return ntohl(n); }
uint16_t ntoh(uint16_t n) { return ntohl(n); }

template <typename OStream>
class Binary_OStream : public OStream
{
  public:
    typedef Binary_OStream This;

    This& write(const char* s, std::streamsize n)
    {
        OStream::write(s, n);
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    This& rawwrite(const T& t)
    {
        static_cast<OStream&>(*this) << '[' << sizeof t << ']';
        return write((const char*)&t, sizeof t);
    }

    template <typename T>
    This& hton(T h)
    {
        T n = ::hton(h);
        return rawwrite(n);
    }

    // conversions for inbuilt & Standard-library types...

    friend This& operator<<(This& bs, bool x) { return bs << (x ? 'T' : 'F'); }
    friend This& operator<<(This& bs, int8_t x) { return bs << x; }
    friend This& operator<<(This& bs, uint8_t x) { return bs << x; }
    friend This& operator<<(This& bs, int16_t x) { return bs.hton(x); }
    friend This& operator<<(This& bs, uint16_t x) { return bs.hton(x); }
    friend This& operator<<(This& bs, int32_t x) { return bs.hton(x); }
    friend This& operator<<(This& bs, uint32_t x) { return bs.hton(x); }

    friend This& operator<<(This& bs, double d) { return bs.rawwrite(d); }

    friend This& operator<<(This& bs, const std::string& x)
    {
        bs << x.size();
        return bs.write(x.data(), x.size());
    }

    template <typename K, typename V, typename A>
    friend This& operator<<(This& bs, const std::map<K, V, A>& m)
    {
        typedef typename std::map<K, V, A>::const_iterator It;

        bs << m.size();

        for (It it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
            bs << it->first << it->second;

        return bs;
    }

    // add any others you want...
};
```

Creating a user-defined binary-serialisable type...

```
// for your own objects...    
struct Object
{
    Object(const std::string& s, double x) : s_(s), x_(x) { }

    std::string s_;
    double x_;

    // specify how you want binary serialisation performed (which fields/order etc)
    template <typename T>
    friend Binary_OStream<T>& operator<<(Binary_OStream<T>& os, const Object& o)
    {
        return os << o.s_ << o.x_;
    }
};
```

Example usage:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

// support routines just to help you observe/debug the serialisation...

std::string printable(char c)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    if (isprint(c))
        oss << c;
    else
        oss << "\\x" << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
            << (int)(uint8_t)c << std::dec;
    return oss.str();
}

std::string printable(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string result;
    for (std::string::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
        result += printable(*i);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    {
        Binary_OStream<std::ostringstream> bs;

        Object o("pi", 3.14);

        bs << o;

        std::cout << "serialised to '" << printable(bs.str()) << "'\n";
    }

    {
        Binary_OStream<std::ostringstream> bs;

        std::map<int, std::string> m;
        m[0] = "zero";
        m[1] = "one";
        m[2] = "two";
        bs << m;

        std::cout << "serialised to '" << printable(bs.str()) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

The next step is to create a `Binary_IStream` - it's very, very similar to the above.  (`boost` reduces the work a little by using the '%' operator instead of the traditional `<<` and `>>`, such that the same function can specify fields for serialiation and deserialisation.)

Implementation notes/thoughts:

- If you prefer, you can remove the template parameter from Binary_Stream, and have a constructor store an arbitrary `std::ostream&` into a `private` member variable, then send all streaming operations to that data member.

  - This has the advantages of minimising code bloat from instantiations for differents stream types, allowing implementation to be hidden from the translation unit and linked in later (helps keep compilation times down in a large project), and letting you just attach a `Binary_Stream` to any existing stream at any time (great if someone's passing you a pre-existing stream).
  - The "disadvantage" is that you have to explicitly forward to any other `ostream` member functions that you want to be accessible to `Binary_Stream` users (more control but tedious), or provide a (less convenient/elegant?) `std::ostream& stream() { return s_; }`-style accessor.